# vimrc setting to ignore file types in netrw

Tags: vim, netrw

What is the setting used in .vimrc to make the netrw directory listing ignore/hide certain file types?

`set wildignore=*.obj,*.exe` only seems to work for tab completion.
Within netrw, you can `ctrl-g` to edit the hiding list, but that only lasts for that session.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

As per http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pi_netrw.html#g:netrw_list_hide, this should work:

```
let g:netrw_list_hide= '.*\.swp$'
```

Comment: You missed the closing quote, but after fixing that, it works. Thanks!

Comment: FYI adding more than one regex requires a comma inside the string. For example: `g:netrw_list_hide= '.*\.swp$,.*\.pyc'`

Comment: Thanks for the addition @brycepg!

Comment: @BryceGuinta Saves my day....the help does not mention this, I don't know why!! (newcomer to lovely vim here)

Comment: If you use NERDTree `let NERDTreeIgnore = ['\.swp$']`